# Having a Case statement for one table in a SQL Union

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to have a `CASE` statement for one table in a SQL `union`, but can't quite figure it out. My first thought gave me an unequal number of columns error and now I am getting a syntax error for the column alias.

```
SELECT
    isd_nm  as "isd",
    CASE 
        WHEN (school_student_id = null) THEN row_id as "student_id"
        ELSE cast(school_student_id as text) as "student_id"
        END,
    school_nm as "school_nm",
    'FormStack' as "source",
    
FROM
    school_reg 
        
UNION
```

I have multiple tables in the union, but this is the only table I need a `CASE` statement as it has null values and I need them to be replaced with a different column when that happens.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running SQL Server? Datatype `text` and the use of double quotes for column identifiers tend to indicate that this is Postgres instead.

Comment: Is it sure you use same column quantity? could you provide bigger part of yours query?

Comment: In SQL Server its a case *expression* i.e. not a statement.

Answer (score 2):

When you compare against `NULL` you must use the operator `IS` and not `=`.
Also the alias of the column must be placed only once after `END` of the `CASE` expression.
You are casting `school_student_id` to `text`. Why? 
Unless its data type is `VARCHAR` the casting will fail, but if it is `VARCHAR` then there is no need to cast it.
Use this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN school_student_id IS null THEN row_id
  ELSE school_student_id
END AS student_id
```

Another way to get the same result with `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(school_student_id, row_id) AS student_id
```

Comment: the DB is a little bit of wonky at the moment and the values are mixed, so that is a temporary workaround while that gets addressed. I tried both ways and both do not return any errors, but also doesn't replace the null values. May be something with the DB. Appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the data type of `school_student_id`? If it is not integer then maybe you don't have nulls but empty strings in the column.